# Alignment of a struct with two doubles is 4 even though double is aligned to 8 (32bit)

Tags: c, gcc, struct, double, memory-alignment

I'm on a x86_64 machine, with Ubuntu 16.04 and gcc 5.4.0.

I've encountered this somewhat strange behavior today.

```
$ cat main.c
#include <stdio.h>
struct dd { double d1; double d2; };
int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", (int)__alignof__(double));
    printf("%d\n", (int)__alignof__(struct dd));
}
$ gcc -m32 -o main main.c && ./main
8
4
```

`__alignof__` returns 8 for `double` and 4 for `struct dd`. I think it is strange for a `struct` to be aligned in smaller unit than its members. This behavior is even contrary to the ISO C standard mentioned in the [gcc 5.4.0 doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.4.0/gcc/Type-Attributes.html):

> Note that the alignment of any given `struct` or `union` type is required by the ISO C standard to be at least a perfect multiple of the lowest common multiple of the alignments of all of the members of the `struct` or `union` in question.

What may be the reason for this behavior? Is aligning this `struct` to 4 byte an optimized way to access memory?

Comment: Have you tried with -std=c99 or -std=c11, if it makes any difference, using just gcc might not be enforcing iso standards

Comment: @Pras I've tried both flags, but same results came out.

Comment: You are misreading the quoted sentence. It does not say "*size* of its members", but "lowest common *alignments* of its members". Do you know what the alignment requirement indeed is?

Comment: By the way, in order to avoid simple mistakes I'd recommend to post a complete example like `cat align.c; gcc -o align -m32 align.c && ./align`, and then the program's output, copied from a terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The document that specifies how this should behave on your architecture is [here, in the i386 System V psABI](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/abi386-4.pdf).  (Current revision [here](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI), see also the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki).  In it we can read that the required alignment of double is 4. But it has this interesting note:

> The Intel386 architecture does not require doubleword alignment for double-precision values. Nevertheless, for data structure compatibility with other Intel architectures, compilers may provide a method to align double-precision values on doubleword boundaries.
>
> A compiler that provides the doubleword alignment mentioned above can
> generate code (data structures and function calling sequences) that do not
> conform to the Intel386 ABI. Programs built with the doubleword alignment
> facility can thus violate conformance to the Intel386 ABI. See ‘‘Aggregates
> and Unions’’ below and ‘‘Function Calling Sequence’’ later in this chapter
> for more information.

GCC doesn't want to violate the ABI for structs (where alignment is quite relevant) so it correctly uses the alignment of 4 for doubles inside structs.

> This behavior is even contrary to the ISO C standard

ISO C is completely irrelevant here since `__alignof__` is not part of any C standard. The compiler could do anything, like fetch a picture of a cat from the internet and show it to you, and that would be a behavior completely compliant with the C standard.

C11 does specify an `_Alignof` operator though. Interestingly enough, if we use the `_Alignof` operator that is part of the C11 standard, GCC reports other (correct) numbers:

```
$ cat foo.c
#include <stdio.h>
struct dd { double d1; double d2; };
int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", (int)__alignof__(double));
    printf("%d\n", (int)__alignof__(struct dd));
}
$ cc -m32 -o foo foo.c && ./foo
8
4
$ ed foo.c
[...]
$ cat foo.c
#include <stdio.h>
struct dd { double d1; double d2; };
int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", (int)_Alignof(double));
    printf("%d\n", (int)_Alignof(struct dd));
}
$ cc -m32 -o foo foo.c && ./foo
4
4
```

---

The wording of the C standard isn't very specific about what should happen in ABIs where types inside structs have lower alignment than they do outside.

[After careful reading of the standard's wording](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52023#c2), and some debate, gcc developers decided that `_Alignof` should tell you the minimum alignment that you will ever see for a value of that type in a strict C11 program (https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2013-12/msg00435.html).  (This is what you want for a use-case like writing a garbage collector that scans blocks of memory for potential pointers.)  Note that C11 doesn't include `__attribute__((packed))`, and casting unaligned pointers is UB.

[This mailing list post](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2013-12/msg00435.html) explains why they changed C11 `_Alignof`, but not C++ `alignof` or the GNU `__alignof__` extension.

GNU C's `__alignof__` continues to mean how gcc will align that type as a global or local, outside of a struct.  i.e. the maximum/recommended alignment.  The current version of the i386 SysV ABI doesn't say anything about aligning `double` to 8B ever; that's purely optional behaviour by current compilers for performance.

Having `_Alignof(double) <= _Align(struct containing_double)` appears to satisfy all the requirements in the C11 standard, even though the preferred alignment for `double` is 8B.  `double` works when crossing a 4B boundary, it's just slow if it crosses a cache-line or page.

(But note that `_Atomic long long` doesn't "work" if it's not 8B aligned, so clang gives it 8B alignment even inside structs.  [Current gcc is broken](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65146#c4) for C11 stdatomic 8B types on the 32-bit SysV ABI, and will hopefully change to match clang.)

---

In clang, `_Alignof` seems to be the same as `__alignof__`.  So it disagrees with gcc about the C11 operator (but not about struct layout, except for C11 stdatomic).

See some test cases [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSBnVAV2OUxAHIBSAJgGY8AO2QAbZlgDU3fgGEGBdAENReYEIB0CGdm4AGAIJ9BI8VJnzFWAGZad%2Bo4eN5rkvQ%2BEFJKtUID6ALZKAB4%2B6tL8ACLequqo1hBBwX5h/gQAlDIAQh5CXgBGzHiiBMIpsf5JqRHRfuW%2B8XWJIfXqfhnZDrleqX6i6Cz5opg1MQ0JoqhCwJIDzEOYmfw5hp6ShcWl/r39g8OjdamNfhCT07N7i52reWNtcwujRwkPw0srBmsbJWW9ryMyWqtITHCD/d5dASYIT4axdG49Cp%2BTwANgALE8KvFTlMZmdgBCEesij9tkjURjAZJDljrE18ZJ8YTHAYCABPAAOmBskgUxGYyC83AA7FlJMgEEpiOLspIAPRyu5CJQMCBozKGSRa7U63U6hkMpTyuWHAgEYh4QoETBNCCpbkQGnjem4xm49LpSQehx63062Ui6LCPkCgjXT63XoU5FCEOCzHjCDB82h5lfElbYExgjomNxoVRanA0HJ/mC5mQwSudxOATCMQSAFyBTKIgBPDIOz8XRE3pKNsd7PohNxBL91Dt5B9Jnh9ObX5I8eToeUwtO0dNJeD0Qz5bw1mc7mYVz5ySlaSiw2kfKdYXRAgAd1QnnDCvZXJ5p5FYr8rInHbdc5DQDO9vAHKdS1DV85XfI8TxTeNv2pP9JzPJ81n7EDoi3CDYwQsM90MWDP3wi8fxQgCv0vV0lGvW9sI5JQ8GILCwP/XD81nSNF3A3NIMQwtnjtcC83wtNbm%2BTM%2B14tFRLLAsgWeTcRP4jpCKMKEYRcBxOHSUhRC4ABWThSCELg9BM1AuFkPgcl4MUmFYdhpAEWgTIIczdL0gBrEB%2BGFDQ0RRfgAE5hRREK0UM3g0TREKUX0rg0RMgI6D0PRTM80grM4EyGBADKPM4Cy9LgWAYCgCqICQNAAg5YpMDICgIFq%2BrhmIFBRCUaY0XS0hrE2Rr8sdOo9EoPT8iy2qAmhAgAHkhFENksvwYhMEFPAADdMHy4qTM8TADL20gqAAR2YRrls4fgNF4DQ3P06FgAIJB6A5NbNrm/IqHWjyRr8MaIAYPAAC8QeGWhDL0IKUT0MLhSitFKGYGFj2EblKGGYBoXQeBDNIDLODcj0PUe6YXroUh3swT7vt%2Byg6gBygqAARQu4g2X4XhaD0YK4t4PQAA4ecF/hDLivRDNoSh8AYDkuqu3TGFB8HMEh6GUVh%2BHEeR1GBqEDHTkwbGYTxgnSCJrzSeGcnXpJ7KOVKKZdoAWgCLnJBd4JkE9ltAXUZhaFoX3FFUG8ojD5BbNsz25v4T2AmsDkghewEGAYEYXcdhA1qUdAE6lCVAUlBgH0O0RPYAdRUCuXcrkEXYIJRmCISZgA7FQXdaqVM/r1AXdUa1iE7tAhG24hgamPKWDYDhaD0o7jMy46cuCQWURd4cxG6mY0Q0PR98kCBcEIEgXP4ehJFkCc2sa8/5/czzSYQTA88a8bSF8qHEs4ZLSFSzWgUQqCzROvfywpQookMsKZeFlspcDygVUgRUSqkDKogEALACAchbuQSgrUGodXoNyU%2BRCF5GRMmZFeXBjDBwfIQBAkg14by3l1c4e8D5wJQV5UgL834dQgOQ3%2BKU/I3ShpDWg/AUS8F4LDfgaJZGwMsggxgSDuGky/hlI6/BKFZRyo/PapUqpVRqjfQheCWpmPaiAYAwpeD9UGhPSgk1jrTVmgtJaK1mK/S2jtLKB0jqoNQI7PAzsuBex9m7D2Ls/ZRADtHeyQcq41yrpgYI5ojR1wbk3FuqA24d1EF3G%2BPdY7xzdknFO2gojp0ztnXO%2Bc3Y1L/o5WedAhFLyoXA1e69N4YmAMgH2AVeBHxPkQaUtDSBXysXfYwvB0gGJKnpPhWABE%2BRAN/I6f9UoI33prQyIUQqhSilDeKSj4G5VUYVJ%2BaCTGYJbjgggFiCHWPsSQsZbSf4dL0TQgQwz6EvSYT04c/TBm3QWTw5Z79BE/y2SAXghkNCHPkelWG4sJZojOfoy5yCn5rI2VwHRmKVHqLWdIjQhkpF6AEJLNEwpDJQwxUdXgIieYZU6coi5JKf7MqJZy3FpBx6TzMmiIAA) with gcc7.2 and clang4.0.  Remove the `-xc` to compile as C++ instead of C

---

somewhat related: gcc7 increased the alignment of `max_align_t` in 32-bit from 8 to 16, [for `_Float128`](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2016-08/msg01898.html), but `malloc(8)` or `strdup("abc")` might still return only 8B-aligned blocks.

[gcc's `stddef.h` implements `max_align_t`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/376cc4e8459bf4aac06e7178367a4907d10e9347/gcc/ginclude/stddef.h#L423) with a struct with members like

```
long long __max_align_ll __attribute__((__aligned__(__alignof__(long long))));
```

to make sure that the resulting struct really does have as large an alignment requirement (`_Alignas`) as its members.  It also has `long double` and `__float128` members.

Comment: Some googling let me stumble over a seasoned developer's (Martin Buchholz) page on which he describes possible implementations of an `align` function; he writes: "On modern x86 processors, the type double is **most efficiently aligned at multiples of 8.** And in fact, gcc aligns "free" doubles at multiples of 8 within stack frames. Unfortunately, ancient ABIs require that the alignment of a double within a struct is 4..." and goes on to describe exactly the issue of the OP. I guess we have the rationale there: Efficiency vs. ABI requirements, probably conceived to reduce padding in structs.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: On actual 386 hardware, there was no performance benefit to more than 4B alignment for `double`, because it didn't have internal caches and it did require two separate bus cycles.  Presumably actual 486 hardware also requires two separate fetches for an 8B load.  It wasn't until Pentium that aligned 8B load/store was guaranteed atomic (implying that it was doing as a single access to cache / memory).  So the ABI design was short-sighted, but not obviously wrong at the time.  (Ordering a struct with the large members first usually gives good behaviour regardless of ABI).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider and Art: See gcc https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52023#c11.  They decided that C11 `_Alignof` should tell you the minimum alignment in the ABI, but `__alignof__` should tell you the maximum / recommended alignment.

Comment: I maybe should have put what I dug up from gcc bug reports and patch messages into an answer of my own.  It got a little longer than I was planning at first.  It fits well in your answer, I think, and just explains why your answer is correct.